Solving a bézier curve backwards
So usually to create a bézier curve; you'd set your origin, control point(s) and target.
However the problem I am facing is that exact process but inverted.
Problem:
For a circle with a given radius, and 2 points present within that circle
Point 1: is centered at 0,0 within the circle (not always but in this case)
Point 2: is dynamic, can be positioned anywhere within the bounds of the circle
The objective is to move P2 towards P1 following a given bézier curve trajectory
Information:
With:
L0(t)=(1-t)*P0+t*P1
L1(t)=(1-t)*P1+t*P2
Q0(t)=(1-t)*L0(t)+t*L1(t)

Where:
P0: origin
P1: control point
P2: target
Q0: current position

I'm given a representation of the desired bézier curve on a small scale:
P0=(0;0)
P1=(0.75;0.25)
P2=(1;1)

I'm then given the coordinates of P0 and Q0 within the circle as well as the radius:
r=1000
P0=(0;0)
Q0=(350;560)

Thoughts:
I'm not sure I understand how I should approach this problem considering the number of unknown variables present and how to scale the smaller representation to the desired size.
Maybe there's information I should deduce, but I am lost at this point
Any thoughts or ideas would be appreciated
Edit:
An idea I had was to scale the given representation to the circle's radius (in this example 1000:1) and then attempt to calculate the deltas between each points for a given step count (ie 500).
From there I would simply apply the delta to the given Q0 to get the next step.
The problem with this idea is that I couldn't find a way to account for vector rotation with this method.
Because the vector wouldn't be rotating clock-wise or counter clock-wise, it would be rotating within the bounds of the circle.

Is your circle centered in (0,0) ?

Indeed, you have two degrees of freedom : you can take any point in the disk as the control point of your Bezier curve.

@JeanMarie In this case the circle is centered at 0,0. But where ever the circle would be located; P0 would be centered in it.
If I was to use any point within the disk, the bezier curve would be different than the desired one... That's basically the conundrum right now
